# Passing an objects id as a parameter when rendering a form_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, for-loop

Am new to developing in Rails and am stuck. I'm trying to pass a player object's id as a parameter to a form to create an availability for a match, based on that players id and the match id. A user has many players and when logged in as current_user can submit availability to matches for their players.

I'm calling this form the match show page, and the match id (4 in the error below) which is being passed is resulting in the error.

```
Couldn't find Player with 'id'=4 [WHERE "players"."user_id" = ?]
```

I'm trying to pass the player.id to the form as a parameter value using render as below.

```
#/views/matches/show.html.erb

<% current_user.players.each do |player| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= player.name %></td>
    <td><%= render 'attend_form', :id => player.id %></td>
  </tr>
```

And then using the player id as a parameter in the 'attend_form' like so.

```
#/views/matches/_attend_form.html.erb

<div id="attend_form">
    <%= form_for (current_user.players.find(params[:id]).availabilities.new(match_id: @match.id)) do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.hidden_field :match_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :player_id, :value => params[:id] %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :available, :value => TRUE %>

    </div>
        <%= f.submit "Attend" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

When submitted, this should then call create in the availabilities controller to create the match availability.

```
#/views/matches/availabilities_controller.rb

def create
    @availability = Availability.new(availability_params)
    if @availability.save
      flash[:success] = "You are now attending this match"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

The relationships between players matches and availabilities are set up as follows:

Match

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :availabilities
has_many :players, through: :availabilities
```

Availability

```
class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :player
belongs_to :match
```

Player

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_many :availabilities, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :matches, through: :availabilities
```

and User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :players
has_many :availabilities
```

Would be very appreciative of any help that can be given on this!  Like I say am new to Rails development.

Comment: So the error is in this line: `Couldn't find Player with 'id'=4 [WHERE "players"."user_id" = ?]` so in what file is this line and what should it do?

Comment: Sorry should have specified.  The error is being generated by line 2 in _attend_form.html.erb.  I think it's where I've used  'current_user.players.find(params[:id])' and it's using the match.id that is passed to the form instead of the player.id.  If I hard code a player id belonging to the current_user in to that line like so '(current_user.players.find(2).availabilities.new(match_id: @match.id)) it takes it and allows the availability to be created.  Thanks.

Comment: can you add something like `<%puts(params[:id])%>` to _attend_form.html.erb and tell me what you get in the console. Also, where is `@match` defined in _attend_form.html.erb?

Comment: puts(params[:id]) returns 12 in the console, which is the id of the match that the availability is being created for.  That's the complete code above for _attend_form.html.erb, so the only place @match is called is in line 2.  The match id is passed from show.html.erb to the form in the URL  as .../matches/12.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears because `current_user` have no `Player` with id == 4 in DB. First you need to check if this player belongs to user and then render form.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's getting 4 from the match id though not the player id.  My problem is with passing the player id to the form_for.  I'm getting match id where I'm trying to pass player id.

Comment: Try to change:
(current_user.players.find(params[:id])
to:
(current_user.players.find(player.id)

Comment: Tried (current_user.players.find(player.id). It's giving the error "NameError in MatchesController#show - undefined local variable or method `player' for #<#<Class:0x .....'